# Installing ODBC in Linux mint

Tags: odbc, linux-mint

I'm trying to install ODBC 17 using the instructions provided in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#ubuntu-1404-1604-1710-and-1804). I am using Linux Mint 19 Cinamon.
After getting the .list file to the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and running apt-get update I get the error in the attached image.
Can anyone help me trying to figure out how to install odbc in linux mint?

[image: Error apt-get update]

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the key:

`curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -`

After adding the keys, try I runned `sudo apt update` again it worked